# JQuery detect lost focus to another element on the page but not lost focus of the browser

Tags: jquery, onblur, lost-focus

Using jquery I am detecting the lost focus on a textbox using the blur event.

I am then hiding the textbox and replacing it with a label containing the text entered.

My problem is that this event is fired even when the browser lose the focus (which under linux/firefox happen even when pressing the "Alt Gr" key to insert a special character like the arobase @ in the textbox)

Is it possible to detect a focus lost only to another element on the page ?

Edit: add example jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/XMp5n/

Relevant code:

```
$('#emailField').blur(function() {
    $('#emailField').hide();
    $('#emailFieldLabel').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code? Also if the browser loses focus, then the control also loses focus, so this is the functionality that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added a small jsfiddle showing the functionality. It is interesting that the blur function is not triggered when clicking another frame inside jsfiddle.

Comment: It seems the losing of the focus with 'Alt Gr' is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/1233458)

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of your JSFiddle appears to work exactly as it should. You mentioned that in `linux/firefox` using the Alt key causes the item to lose focus, to correct this you may need to add a global variable and change this in the 'document.onkeydown' function :

```
        var isAlt = false;

        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 18) {
                isAlt = true;
            } else {
                isAlt = false;
            }
        }

        $('#emailField').blur(function() {
            if (isAlt) {
                $('#emailField').hide();
                $('#emailFieldLabel').show();
            }
        });
```

Check [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) for other Javascript keycodes.

Comment: Nice try but it doesn't work because the blur event is triggered before the onkeydown event.